Reload pagination function to use updated variable when variable is updated
I am trying to update the pagination of of Javascript object whenever the variable with that object is filtered.
Ex: 5 page pagination becomes 2 pages when click button to filter the array to only show objects that have a certain category.
I'm currently passing the master array to the pagination via a testToShow variable and the testToShow is updated onClick to filter the array based on category names.
My issue:
The testToShow variable updates to a new value whenever the testToShow variable is filtered onClick but the showPage pagination function does not update based on the new array value.
Currently it just redirects to page one but is still based on the original variable value.
HTML:
<button role="tab" aria-selected="true" class="btn-secondary btn-filter" onclick="filterTests('PZ')">Personalization</button>

<div class="pagination">
                                    <div id="ux-results" class="tableList accordion-group">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="pagination-block pagination flex">
                                        <span class="pageButton material-icons" id="button_prev">
                                            keyboard_arrow_left
                                        </span>
                                        <span id="page_number" class="outline-none"></span>
                                        <span class="pageButton material-icons" id="button_next">
                                            keyboard_arrow_right
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>

Example of Javascript Object:
const uxTests = [
    {
       category: "Ecomm", 
       projectName: "Project Name 1",
       date: "TBD", 
       details: "Objective: TBD",
       resultsLink: "https://www.google.com",
       isStillTesting: true,
   },
   {
       category: "PZ", 
       projectName: "Project Name 2",
       date: "TBD", 
       details: "Objective: TBD",
       resultsLink: "https://www.google.com",
       isStillTesting: true,
   },
 ]

Update variable:
let testToShow = uxTests;

function filterTests(category) {
    let testToShow = uxTests.filter(test => test.category.includes(category.toString()));

    showPage();
}

Pagination function:
function showPage() {
        "use strict";        
    
        function Pagination() {
    
          const prevButton = document.getElementById('button_prev');
          const nextButton = document.getElementById('button_next');
          const clickPageNumber = document.querySelectorAll('.clickPageNumber');
          
          let current_page = 1;
          let records_per_page = 5;
          
          this.init = function() {
              changePage(1);
              pageNumbers();
              selectedPage();
              clickPage();
              addEventListeners();
         }
          
          let addEventListeners = function() {
              prevButton.addEventListener('click', prevPage);
              nextButton.addEventListener('click', nextPage);   
          }
                
          let selectedPage = function() {
              let page_number = document.getElementById('page_number').getElementsByClassName('clickPageNumber'); 
              for (let i = 0; i < page_number.length; i++) {
                  if (i == current_page - 1) {
                      page_number[i].style.fontWeight = "bold";
                  } 
                  else {
                      page_number[i].style.fontWeight = "normal";
                  }
              }   
          }  
          
          let checkButtonStatus = function() {
            current_page == 1 ? prevButton.classList.add("deactivate")  : prevButton.classList.remove("deactivate");
            current_page == numPages() ? nextButton.classList.add("deactivate") : nextButton.classList.remove("deactivate");
          }
    
          let changePage = function(page) {
              const results = document.getElementById('ux-results');
    
              if (page < 1) {
                  page = 1;
              } 
              if (page > (numPages() -1)) {
                  page = numPages();
              }
           
              results.innerHTML = "";
    
              for(var i = (page -1) * records_per_page; i < (page * records_per_page) && i < testToShow.length; i++) {
                  results.innerHTML += `
                    <div class="accordion-item ${testToShow[i].category.toLowerCase()}">
                        <button class="accordion-btn" aria-expanded="false">
                            <div class="flex">
                                <span class="dot ${testToShow[i].isStillTesting ? 'testing' : ''}"></span>
                                <div class="title">
                                    ${testToShow[i].projectName}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <i class="material-icons">expand_more</i>
                        </button>
                        <div class="accordion-content">
                            <div class="accordion-content-body">
                                <div class="flex">
                                    <div>
                                        <div class="test-date">${testToShow[i].date}</div>
                                        <p>
                                            ${testToShow[i].details}
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                    <a href="${testToShow[i].resultsLink}">View Full Results</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  `;
              }
              checkButtonStatus();
              selectedPage();
              accordion();
          }
    
          let prevPage = function() {
              if(current_page > 1) {
                  current_page--;
                  changePage(current_page);
              }
          }
    
          let nextPage = function() {
              if(current_page < numPages()) {
                  current_page++;
                  changePage(current_page);
              } 
          }
    
          let clickPage = function() {
              document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    
                  if(e.target.nodeName == "SPAN" && e.target.classList.contains("clickPageNumber")) {
                    console.log("clicked page");
    
                      current_page = e.target.textContent;
                      changePage(current_page);
                  }
              });
          }
    
          let pageNumbers = function() {
              let pageNumber = document.getElementById('page_number');
                  pageNumber.innerHTML = "";
    
              for(let i = 1; i < numPages() + 1; i++) {
                  pageNumber.innerHTML += "<span class='clickPageNumber'>" + i + "</span>";
              }
          }
    
          let numPages = function() {
              return Math.ceil(testToShow.length / records_per_page);  
          }
       }
      let pagination = new Pagination();
      pagination.init();

}

window.onload = showPage(); 

